# JavaFX bidirectional binding of two different, non-String, ListProperty

Tags: binding, javafx, observablelist

I need to bind together two ListProperties:

```
ObservableList<Data<Number, Number>>    chartDataList       = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
ListProperty<Data<Number, Number>>      chartDataProperty   = new SimpleListProperty<>(this, "chartData", chartDataList);
ObservableList<Point2D>                 observableData      = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
ListProperty<Point2D>                   dataProperty        = new SimpleListProperty<>(this, "Data", observableData);
```

`chartDataList` will be used to display a LineChart, while the other (`data`) will be used in the rest of my program. `chartDataProperty` is not really needed (but for binding), because `LineChart` uses just `chartDataList`.

**Note**: binding needs to be bidirectional because I have means to manually drag the points on the `LineChart` using mouse.

I didn't find a direct way to handle this; only conversion seems to be to/from `String` (or `ListProperty<String>`). I could use that, with man-in-the-middle `ListProperty<String>`, but it looks *very* inefficient.

Otherwise I need to resort to `ChangeListner` usage, manually handling all possible cases.

Please tell me I have some better choice.

Comment: You can use [EasyBind](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind) to do uni-directional binding of lists, but not bidirectional binding, I think. Can you not just update the `observableData` list in response to the mouse drags?

Comment: You are right. I neeed only mono-directional. I will check if that doesn't slow too much rendering, but THANKS!